# Turning specific object fields into Json

Tags: c#, json

I have a nested object

```
public class CardListViewModel
{

    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }


    public virtual IEnumerable<Card> CardList { get; set; }

}

public class Card
{       
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string IndexName { get; set; }

    public virtual Image CardImage { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
//... 
public virtual string Src { get; set; }
//...
}
```

So card may be

```
CardListViewModel.CardList[0] = {Id:5678, IndexName:"Visa", {Src:"Visa.png"}}
CardListViewModel.CardList[1] = {Id:5555, IndexName:"MasterCard", {Src:"MasterCard.png"}}
```

The result I want is a Json object like the following

```
{
    "Visa": "Visa.png",
    "MasterCard": "MasterCard.png"
}
```

I can't modify the POCO, all I want is a JSON fragment for each card in the list and their corresponding image.  Of course I can brute force this with `StringBuilder` and loops, but I was wondering if there was a way to accomplish this with the `JsonConvert` library or any other good tools that handle the mapping for me?

Comment: What should happen to `Card.Id`?  Is it simply omitted?  Can you share your desired JSON for the root `CardListViewModel` rather than just the fragment related to the `CardList`?

Comment: So I can't modify the POCO, all I want is a Json fragment for each card in the list and their corresponding image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use LINQ to map it and NewtonsoftJson to build the JSON.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Linq;

var mappedCards = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new JObject (
  from card in CardListViewModel.CardList
  select new JProperty(card.IndexName, card.CardImage.Src)));
```

Comment: Thank you it was the JProperty that I did not know about

Answer (score 0):

Given that *I can't modify the POCO* and you are looking to use [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net), you can create a [custom `JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for objects of type `IEnumerable<Card>` as follows:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

public class CardListConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(IEnumerable<Card>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var list = existingValue as ICollection<Card> ?? new List<Card>();
        var obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        foreach (var property in obj.Properties())
        {
            list.Add(new Card { IndexName = property.Name, CardImage = new Image { Src = (string)property.Value } });
        }
        return list;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var collection = (IEnumerable<Card>)value;
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            writer.WritePropertyName(item.IndexName);
            writer.WriteValue(item.CardImage == null ? null : item.CardImage.Src);
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```

Then use it in serialization settings as follows:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new CardListConverter() },
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(CardListViewModel, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

And your `CardListViewModel` will be serialized as follows:

```
{
  "Id": "c2a7cc0f-0e6b-40a0-9020-aeba436265d4",
  "CardList": {
    "Visa": "Visa.png",
    "MasterCard": "MasterCard.png"
  }
}
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EezjAb).